# Should chemistry-related forensics questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

Often the field of forensics involves a good deal of chemistry—should we allow forensics-related questions on the site?

Answer (score 7):

Forensic chemistry is a huge field that intersects with analytical chemistry, materials chemistry, biochemistry, environmental chemistry, toxicology, pharmacology, safety and reliability engineering and many more fields. Realistically, forensics is a *context* in which questions in these fields are asked and as such questions are probably going to be interesting and noteworthy in their own right. Popular CSI-type TV shows promulgate a lot of fantastic blather and a few expert level answers on chem.SE could be the antidote.

As long as questions don't fall foul of [this topic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/how-should-we-handle-questions-on-energetic-materials-and-bioactive-compounds) or *'this body is taking too long to dissolve - how can I speed things up?'*...